# windows azure notifications hub TAGS

Tags: android, azure, notifications

I'm working with Windows Azure Notification Hub and Android, testing the notifications push service through GCM.
I'm using tags, pushing notifications from a Web aplication (back-end) integrated with Windows Azure, and subscribing from an Android App to listen to those tags.

The issue is: I don't know how to unsubscribe from those tags. Even when I restart the app in the emulator and without registering with GCM nor Azure I continue receiving notifications for each tag I have suscribed previously.

Where are these tags stored? how can I stop listening to those tags?

Comment: Based on the build talk (http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2014/2-616) I just finished listening to the tags are only stored on the Hub backend and are overwritten on each registration, have you tried sending an empty tag list (I have yet to check out the API so not sure how you'd do this)?

Answer (score 2):

Also you can remove azure notification hub registration using Visual Studio (server explorer, azure, hubs, remove from device lists).

Also if your GCM regenerated(or expired) notification hub removes registration when trying to send message on non-existent GCM.

P.S. you shouldn't create new registration on hub any time you restart your app. Better way - store regId on device and use it on backand to check if registration exists.

Comment: Didn't know you could view Hub registrations in Visual Studio, thanks!  Strange that registering the same device ID with different tags can sometimes create multiple registrations (rather than overwriting).

Comment: Because DeviceId isn't UniqId for azure notification hub registration(it's got registration Id))) If you wanna override - you should keep registration ids (on mobile for example), and before creating new registration - check "if registration exists, then get and update, else generate new id and create".

Comment: Thanks - I tried looking for a way to do that, but only high-level `register`/`unregister` methods seem available in Android API for [NotificationHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-notificationhubs/blob/master/Android/notification-hubs-sdk/src/main/java/com/microsoft/windowsazure/messaging/NotificationHub.java)

Answer (score 0):

Once you have received Registration Id from GCM it can be used to send messages to your application at any time even if application is restarted.

Basically, when you call NotificationHub.register(...) that Registration Id and tags specified are sent to your Azure Notification Hub (NH). Then when your backend sends a message to tag "A" NH just scans its list of registrations looking for tag "A". Then all registrations with tag "A" are sent with the message via GCM endpoint. So your application receives that message.

To stop receiving notifications you can just call NotificationHub.unregister(...).

Also GCM can expire Registration Id after some time, then NH will figure it out and remove that Id from its DB.

Also if application is not active for 90 days then NH automatically removes Registration Id from DB as expired.